# Swift 3 - Invalid conversion from throwing function type '(Any) -> Void'

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm new to swift and 
I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error.

I've being reading similar questions and so far none of them solved this error or I have not found it:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()'
>   to non-throwing function type '(Any) -> ()'

At the line:

```
self.ws.event.message = { message in
```

The piece of code with the error:

```
public var ws = WebSocket()

public func websocket(token: Any){
        self.ws.open("ws://"+String(APIHOST)+":"+String(port)+"/ws?token="+String(describing: token))

        self.ws.event.message = { message in
            if let text = message as? String {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: text, options: []) as? [String: Any]

                print("recv: \(text)")
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's the meaning of `self.ws.event.message = { message in`? Isn't it missing a method?

Comment: What is `self.ws`? What is `ws.event.message` defines as?

Comment: In JSONSerialization first arguement should be `Data` type instead of String.

Comment: The problem is that I receive a notification as String and I need to pass this to JSON

Comment: self.ws is the way to call public var ws = WebSocket ()

Comment: @BelenDominguezGarcia you cannot convert String type message to Json Object, if message is json string then you need to convert it to Data first then it will be converted into json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below piece of code

```
public var ws = WebSocket()

public func websocket(token: Any){
    self.ws.open("ws://"+String(APIHOST)+":"+String(port)+"/ws?token="+String(describing: token))

    self.ws.event.message = { message in
        if let dataObj = message as? Data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:dataObj, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                print("recv: \(text)")
            } catch error {
                print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function that throws something, it usually means there might be a chance of error when accessing that data in your case JSON.

If function throws you need to do {} catch {} to tell Swift you are going to handle an error.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Using do {} and catch {}, it no longer throws the problem

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebSocket implementation but I do know Swift allows for native JSON implementation using Codable Protocol.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types